# Magento : Need to Change Custom Order Status

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, order-status

When order is complete, then set order status to `Payment Complete` and once they set Courier status then it should be made as `Completed`.

Comment: will you explain more

Answer (score 0):

You should go to:

```
Admin->System->Order Statuses
```

Below points may be helpful for you:

1. There are two things **state** & **status**
2. State can not be add (some default state managed by Magento only),but status can.
3. Only thing you can do is, create new status & set as default status for that particular state.
4. Yes, you have to find out which state you want to change the order status.